# Getting Null pointer exception while accessing BroadCasted Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting Null pointer exception when broadcasting a Dataframe and trying to access them in a Spark UDF.

UDF definition-

```
def test_udf(parm1: String,  parm2: String,  paarm3: String,  ) = {
println ("Inside UDF ")           
B.value.take(1).foreach { println }
println("after print")
```

..... 
....... }

```
> sqlContext.udf.register("test_udf", test_udf _)
```

Broadcasting-

```
val B = sc.broadcast(sqlContext.sql("""Select * FROM table_a where col1='10102'""")) // Returns almost 20 MB data
```

Accessing UDF-

```
val df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT test_udf(parm1,parm2,parm3) AS test FROM table_b").take(1)
```

After this line i am getting null pointer exception in UDF at below line B.value.take(1).foreach { println }

I am suspecting that Broadcast is not happening correctly. Is it something wrong in this code? Using Spark 1.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an exception because it is not a valid Spark program:

- broadcasting `DataFrame` object is not a meaningful operation. This is why we [have broadcast join hints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37487318/1560062).
- Spark doesn't support nested operations on distributed data structure. In other words you cannot access `DataFrame` inside an UDF.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Join is not possible because keys are not in table_b for join. I need to do a lookup through table_a for pulling right value. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Unless it is local structure (collected rows for example) it is not possible without joining data.

Comment: Thank you. Your both points are very right. Learnt it the hard way.

Comment: Thanks. Post helped me to actually fix legacy code.