# Broadcast join to join two dataframes in SPARK efficiently

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, pyspark, hadoop-partitioning

I am having a `DataFrame` `df1` which has some 2 Million rows. I have already repartitioned it on the basis of a key called `ID`, since the data was `ID` based -

```
df=df.repartition(num_of_partitions,'ID')
```

Now, I wish to join this `df` to a relatively small sized `DataFrame` `df2`, on the basis of a common column `hospital_code`, but I do not want to lose my `ID` based partitioning of `df` -

```
df.join(df1,'key','left')
```

I have read that in case one DataFrame is larger than the other, then it's a good idea to use `broadcast` joins like shown below and this would maintain the partitioner of the larger DataFrame `df`. But, I am not certain of it.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast
df.join(broadcast(df1),'key','left')
```

Can anyone suggest as to what is the efficient way to approach this problem and how can we maintain the partitioner of the larger `DataFrame` without making many compromises on latency and shuffle related issues etc?

Comment: It will maintain the partitioning of the larger data frame as a copy of the small data frame is sent to each partition of the larger data frame and then relevant rows are merged together

Comment: Thanks for your comments.So, you want to say that there is no need to `broadcast` the `df2` and the join `df.join(df1,'key','left')` is as good as it could possibly be? Is it still the most efficient way?

Comment: nothing here to answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487318/spark-sql-broadcast-hash-join

Comment: Depends on the size of the smaller data frame. Look here for some pitfalls of broadcast join and configurations that control it https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12837

Comment: Well, it around 500 rows in the small dataframe as opposed to 2 million in the bigger one.

Comment: Thanks eliasah for a very useful link. It's clear many of my misgivings. This link shows it pictorially https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-spark/9781491943199/ch04.html