# How can I query a table using the data in a column of an existing dataframe in Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe `df` that looks something like this.

```
+----+
| Id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
+----+
```

What I want to do is use this `Id` column in a SQL query to pull information from another table. This table I'm querying is massive so querying the entire thing and then doing a join isn't performant.

I tried something like this.

`spark.sql(f"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Id IN {df.Id}")`

but that doesn't seem to work. Is there another way to do what I'm attempting here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [broadcast join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37487575/2129801). If you broadcast the `df` dataframe it would be no problem if `mytable` is large:

```python
result=spark.sql("""select /*+  BROADCASTJOIN(df) */ *   
                from mytable join df on mytable.id = df.id""")
```